# Error #1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. Macro will stop

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to find a way to resolve my problem, but I couldn't do it. I found a code to import an information from one excel file to another one. I re-worked it with my sheet naming and columns numbering, but when I tried to run it, it gave me an error: "Error #1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. Macro will stop". Could you please help me with it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo errorhandler
Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RngFleetData, rng As Range
Dim x As Variant
Dim countryN, counnty As String

Dim lReadFirstRow As Long
Dim lReadLastRow As Long
Dim lWriteFirstRow As Long
Dim lWriteLastRow As Long
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim NumOfMonth As Double
filenev = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
NRRowsRange = 1

 x = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Spreadsheets ,*.xls*", , "Open File")
If x = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ThisWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(x, False, True)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect

 copied = 0

 j = 1
 Do While Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 1) <> "fields extract"
 j = j + 1
 Loop
 j = j + 3

 i = 0
 Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) <> ""
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) <> 0 Then

        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 12)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 13)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 16)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 19)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 20)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 7) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 22)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 8) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 23)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 24)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 10) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 25)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 11) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 26)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 12) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 27)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 13) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 28)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 14) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 32)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 15) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 33)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 16) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 34)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 17) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 35)
        Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 18) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11)


    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").EntireRow.Delete
       If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = 0 Then Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").EntireRow.Delete
       Application.Goto Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 1)
       ActiveCell.Rows(NRRowsRange).EntireRow.Select
       Selection.Copy
       Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
       copied = 1



j = j + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

If copied = 1 Then
ActiveCell.Rows(NRRowsRange).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Delete
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


MsgBox "fields has been imported sucessfully!"

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Activate

errorhandler:
Select Case Err.Number
Case 9
MsgBox "Hey Buddy, this is NOT the right extract! Macro will STOP", vbExclamation, "STOP"
ThisWorkbook.Close False
Case 0
Case Else
MsgBox "Error # " & Err & " : " & Error(Err) & "Macro will STOP"
End Select
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you run it in debug mode putting few break points by pressing `F8`? Then let us know exactly which line you are getting the error? By the way, I wouldn't use a name like `ThisWorkbook` here. You may change it to something else although it might not be the issue.

Comment: + 1 @bonCodigo: It is a valid point. `ThisWorkbook` is a reserved name. Also :@Aquila: Comment the line `On Error GoTo errorhandler` and tell us which line is giving the error...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I changed the name on ThisWorkbook to AutoWorkbook and also I run it on debug mode. The error is starting from - i = 0
 Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) <> "", I guess, because after the Loop it turn me back

Comment: Just saw your edit. I already posted an answer with the errors that I have noticed...

Answer (score 2):

I see an error in this line

```
 i = 0
 Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) <> ""
```

The first row cannot be `0`

Change `i = 0` to `i = 1` and try again.

I also see an error in these lines

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").EntireRow.Delete
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = 0 Then Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").EntireRow.Delete
```

Which row do you want to delete? You have to mention the row. For example

```
Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Rows(1).Delete
```

---

### **EDIT**

---

Sorry couldn't help but give this advice. I noticed few things which I thought that I'll point out

**A**. use `Option Explicit` This will ensure that you declare all variables. Now, why is this important? There are two main reasons for using `Option Explicit`

a). It forces you to declare your variables as a specific data type.

b). It keeps a watch on your code checking for spelling mistake that might happen when you type your variable.

You might also want to read [this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/)?

**B** Use proper handling. This is required so that you can trap errors and also not to mention "Restore Defaults"

For example, you are setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` What happens if you get and error? I would recommend something like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Sample()
    Dim clc As Long

    On Error GoTo errorhandler

    clc = Application.Calculation

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    '
    '~~> REST OF YOUR CODE
    '

LetsContinue:
    Application.Calculation = clc '<~~ Reset Calc
    Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 9
        MsgBox "Hey Buddy, this is NOT the right extract! Macro will STOP", vbExclamation, "STOP"
        ThisWorkbook.Close False
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error # " & Err & " : " & Error(Err) & "Macro will STOP"
    End Select
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest, I didn't debug the code LOL... Just gave it a normal glance so I am not sure that these are the only errors. There might be more. Let's see what the OP says after he/she makes the above changes and runs the code.

Comment: My eyes get boggled if I look at certains codes no offense... I dont mind writting some logics, but debugging.. although it's part and partial.. :D

Comment: Thank you for that! I editted the code and now when the system gave me this error it's showing me the Debug error into the "Do While Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("CEP auto").Cells(j, 1) <> "fields extract"" line.

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you have a sheet called `CEP auto`? The code in your question shows that it should be `Auto`. So which one is it?

Comment: which line are you getting the error?? If it is the same line then change the line to `Do While InStr(1, Workbooks(filenev).Sheets("auto").Cells(j, 1), "fields extract", vbTextCompare) > 0` Also ensure that that you have `fields extract` in Col A else you will get an error if the value of `j` reaches the total rows count...